# Is this song (Shpigel) a cover of something?

Tags: cover, parody

The Hasidic Jewish artist Chaim Shlomo Mayes is quite famous for his Hasidic covers and parodies of songs. For instance, he made a song called "[Bas Kol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiEtusobEA4)" which is obviously a parody of "Worth It" by Fifth Harmony.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6H7JBGb7V4c) is the song. It's called "Shpigel", which means "mirror" in Yiddish. (Yes, I already know the translation of the lyrics, LOL.)

I don't listen to secular music; all my knowledge comes from being out and about - and I have never heard a song while out that sounds like this one.

Comment: I can't access to the video. It seems unavailable... can you check it, please?

Comment: @Bebs - Yeah, the video works by me. Here's the link again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6H7JBGb7V4c

Comment: I had trouble with the link too. you can  listen to a sample on [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9C/id1053962968).  SoundHound only recognises the song as itself, so not an obvious parody of something else, I'm guessing.  You could maybe ask a question via his [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/chaim_mayes?lang=en)

Comment: @Angst - Um, I don't know what to say as far as the link goes. You can always just type the word "Shpigel" into YouTube and the song is the first result.

Comment: @ezra I tried too, but I had no relevant results... Don't forget that results may vary depending on the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a cover/parody/translation of the song "Mirror" by Lil Wayne ft. Bruno Mars

He pretty much just translated all the words form the original song into Yiddish (unlike what he did with "Bas Kol")

---

[YouTube video of Mirrors](https://youtu.be/OZLUa8JUR18)

It may be a bit uncomfortable to watch that video, [here](https://youtu.be/Oi1UunggOAs) is a link for an audio-only video with lyrics.